# Error in Python lib argparse method parse_args()

Tags: python, pytest, argparse

I am writing my Integration Tests code then I have a Parent `BaseTestClass` class to be extended to the children's classes. The Parent Base Class should read dynamic properties from the resource `yaml` files to be easy to change the environment etc. The test framework to be used is `pytest`.

Once I execute the below code, an error is triggered in the line where I am parsing the arguments: `args = parser.parse_args()`. My clues to find out the error are over.

*test_base.py*

```
import yaml
import pytest
import argparse


class BaseTestClass:
    @classmethod
    def configure(cls):
        print('Configure')
        # Read env from CLI args
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--env',
                            choices=['local', 'dev', 'qa', 'prod'],
                            help='The execution environment',
                            default='local')
        args = parser.parse_args() # Code is breaking here.
        env = args.env
        with open(f"resources/config-{env}.yaml", 'r') as file:
            properties = yaml.safe_load(file)
            cls.config = properties

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def configure_parent(self):
        self.configure()
```

Error log:

```
ERROR                      [100%]Configure
usage: _jb_pytest_runner.py [-h] [--env {local,dev,qa,prod}]
_jb_pytest_runner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /Users/agstcadini/Projects/quinta/quinta-app/python/quinta-backend/tests/integration

test setup failed
self = <test_api.TestApi object at 0x10dc523d0>

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def configure_parent(self):
>       self.configure()

test_base.py:24: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
test_base.py:16: in configure
    args = parser.parse_args()
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/argparse.py:1827: in parse_args
    self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/argparse.py:2581: in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = ArgumentParser(prog='_jb_pytest_runner.py', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
status = 2
message = '_jb_pytest_runner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /Users/agstcadini/Projects/quinta/quinta-app/python/quinta-backend/tests/integration\n'

    def exit(self, status=0, message=None):
        if message:
            self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
>       _sys.exit(status)
E       SystemExit: 2

/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/argparse.py:2568: SystemExit
```

Filesystem

```
% tree -v -L 2
.
├── __pycache__
│   ├── test_api.cpython-39-pytest-7.3.1.pyc
│   └── test_base.cpython-39-pytest-7.3.1.pyc
├── report.json
├── resources
│   ├── config-dev.yaml
│   └── config-local.yaml
├── test_api.py
└── test_base.py
```

*config-local.yaml*

```
endpoint:
  host: localhost
  port: 8081
```

Comment: Does this run as regular script call?  With or without the '--env' value? testing any user interaface is tricky.  `parse_aegs()` reads `sys.argv`. In pytest those values are used by tester, and not suitable for your parser.  Read the `usage` line.  The tester put a '--json' argument is sys.argv.  That's meant for a jupyter (or similar) notebook.  Your parser can't handle that.

Comment: The argparse error is `usage: _jb_pytest_runner.py [-h] [--env {local,dev,qa,prod}]
_jb_pytest_runner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --json=report.json /Users/agstcadini/Projects/quinta/quinta-app/python/quinta-backend/tests/integration`  The rest is the test environment error catching.

Comment: How do I'd handle it in case I need to pass further arguments? Also, I removed the `--json` argument then updated the log in the question.

Comment: You can use `parse_known_args` instead, but usually, you only deal with `argparse` on script entry, not "deeper" in your code. If test cases need information from a configuration file, your test *runner* should be responsible for passing that information in.

Comment: there are many other SO about [argparse] and [pytest]

Comment: The idea is to have a Base Test Class to be extended to all other Test Classes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved changing basically two lines:

1. Setting up the `argparse` constructor argument `allow_abbrev=False`

   `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=False)`
2. Getting `args` through `parse_known_args`.

   `args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()`

So the code looks like this:

**BaseTestClass**

```
import yaml
import pytest
import argparse
from dependency_injector import providers


class BaseTestClass:
    port = None
    hostname = None

    @classmethod
    def configure(cls):
        config = providers.Configuration('config')

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(allow_abbrev=False)
        parser.add_argument('--env',
                            choices=['local', 'dev', 'qa', 'prod'],
                            help='The execution environment',
                            default='local')
        args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
        env = args.env
        with open(f"resources/config-{env}.yaml", 'r') as file:
            properties = yaml.safe_load(file)

        config.from_dict(properties)

        # Access the injected dependencies
        cls.hostname = config.endpoint.hostname()
        cls.port = config.endpoint.port()

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def configure_parent(self):
        self.configure()
```

**ApiTest**

```
import requests
from test_base import BaseTestClass


class TestApi(BaseTestClass):
    def test_insert_transaction(self):
        payload = {
            "name": "John",
            "age": 30
        }

        hostname = self.hostname
        port = self.port

        response = requests.post(f"http://{hostname}:{port}/transaction", json=payload)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

***config-local.yaml***

```
endpoint:
  hostname: localhost
  port: 8081
```

Execute: `$ pytest`